# how to display different values on focus and on blur in autocomplete component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to display different value depends on focus/blur autocomplete input.

Let's say we have suggestions of items where each item has `id` and `desc`. I want to filter items by `id` and by `desc`. When I select one of them and input is blur there should be `id` and `desc` displayed (e.g. 1 - item01).

When focus is back on input it should display only `id` (without `desc`) and if any suggestions with that `id`(like if 10 is there it should suggest 1010 | desc ). Right now I have to forcefully erase the `desc` to get back to `id`. That shouldn't be the case.

Thanks for any suggestions.

You can try to edit [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vk79pv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

See expected behavior on image:

[image]

Comment: So you want the description to be erased automatically on re-focusing and only the id should be there ?

Comment: Try to use pipe. I've made a sample which could give you a kick off https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mssmik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Control Value Accessor (CVA)

The [**ControlValueAccessor**](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface is what you are looking for.

*Why*? This interface decouples the DOM from the Angular Form allowing the display drop down and input to differ from the value that is actually used by the form.

You can implement a custom input as a separate component* and pass a FormControl in.

The following is an untested [Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so57273454-cva)

***Edit 3** - I believe it may also possible to implement this as a directive. See -  [Angular 2 Directive implementing ControlValueAccessor doesn't update 'touched' property on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694521)

---

### Outside the black box

Your *app.component.html* will end up looking like.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <app-auto-special [users]="options" [formControl]="myControl"></app-auto-special>
</form>
```

*app-auto-special* acts like a blackbox where it cares only about the User id.

We can patchValue or setValue and it will do it's thing (call *writeValue* internally). If we interact with this component we get User id's for the FormControl value.

**Edit** - nothing is stopping you passing the whole User object around instead. I'm assumed OP wanted id based on the question.

**Edit 2** - Example passing User object instead [Working Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so57273454-cva-user)

---

### Inside the black box

We need to register the *app-auto-special* component as a provider for the controlValueAccessor using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR. This is done via:

```
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => AutoSpecialComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
```

So inside the black box we implement the interface comprising of 4 methods:

1. `writeValue(obj: any): void`
2. `registerOnChange(fn: any): void`
3. `registerOnTouched(fn: any): void`
4. `setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean)?: void`

This usually means the following boilerplate:

```
export class AutoSpecialComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  public _value: number;
  public disabled: boolean;
  onChanged: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  /*
  * ControlValueAccessor boilerplate
  *
  */
  writeValue(value): void {
    this._value = value
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChanged = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled
  }

}
```

We make a copies of the functions provided by `registerOnChange` and `registerOnTouched` and call these copies (`this.onChanged` and `this.onTouched`) when we want to update the formControl value or it's on touched property. `setDisabledState` is optional and `writeValue` is called on initialization or when we call `patchValue` or `setValue` from the parent.

To set the FormControl we call `this.onChanged(some_value);` and we can hook into various events `input`, `focusin`, `blur`, `optionSelected` and decide what happens separately to:

- The FormControl value
- Which options to show
- What display string should be in the input

---

*This answer comes with the caveat that this is one of the first CVA implementations I've done so I'm shaky on the foundations.*

---

### Additional benefits

- Unit testing - isolated DOM display versus form
- Separation of logic - parent no longer saturated

### Resources

Learn more from the following youtube video [The Control Value Accessor | Jennifer Wadella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVbLSN0AW-Y)

This is accompanied by the following [slides](https://tehfedaykin.github.io/WormholesandCVAs)

Comment: This has potential if reuse is needed, but would have to be modified quite a bit to allow for using different data sets and formatting. Otherwise this is probably heavy-handed. It also assumes that form control values can be just the 'id' - not the entire 'User' object that the OP uses. And it needs work as it isn't working properly - focus, select, blur, focus results in the display text being just the id.

Comment: @G.Tranter per OP...When focus is back on input it should display only id. And absolutely nothing is stopping you from passing the User to the formcontrol

Comment: My bad -  I realise now what you are saying, onBlur should should show id and descr. This is now fixed.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gz8jd5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Sergey - still needs the fix I mentioned before you deleted your answer (it was a great answer) - you can't type into the field. Fixed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcb71e?file=src/app/input-focus.pipe.ts.

Comment: @Sergey please repost my updated answer below as your own and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

Updated:

Building on a deleted answer from user @Sergey, all you need to do is to add a pipe and a template reference to the input element. No other changes are necessary:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcb71e?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-focus.pipe.ts)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Assignee" aria-label="Assignee" 
  matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  #input [value]="myControl.value | inputFocus:input.ownerDocument.activeElement === input">
```

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'inputFocus'
})
export class InputFocusPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, focused: boolean): any {
    if (!value || typeof value === 'string') { 
      return value; 
    }

    return focused ? value.id : value.id + ' | ' + value.description;
  }

}
```