# Create a reusable custom select dropdown component in Angular Reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a custom reusable select-input component in **Angular Reactive Forms**.
The component should be used in parent component form (register form in my case).
But i am not able to **detect changes on child component** (select-input component) pass them to the parent component.
Here is what i have tried

***select-input.component.ts***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-input',
  templateUrl: './select-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-input.component.css']
})
export class SelectInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor 
{
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() options: {value: string}[];
  
  constructor() { }

  writeValue(obj: any): void
  {
    
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void
  {
    
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void
  {
    
  }
}
```

***select-input.component.html***

```
<div>
    <label for={{name}} style="margin-right: 2px;">{{label}}:</label>
    <select name={{name}}>
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
            {{option.value}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

***register.component.ts***

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit 
{
  countries: {name: string}[] = [
    {value: 'Canada'},
    {value: 'USA'},
    {value: 'UK'},
    {value: 'Japan'},
  ]
  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
    this.initializeForm();
  }
  
  initializeForm()
  {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      country: [this.countries]
    })
    
  }
}
```

***register.component.html***

```
<select-input [formControl]='registerForm.controls["country"]' ngDefaultControl
        [label]='"Country"' [name]='"countries"' [options]="countries">
</select-input>
```

How can detect changes on child component(select-input) and propagate them on parent component(register-form) ?

Comment: How to propagate them - You call the `onChanged` copy of `fn` callback you copied when `registerOnChange` runs. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57280011/4711754)

Comment: How can you eleborate on that ? Thanks

Comment: `registerOnChange(fn: any) { this.onChanged = fn }` i.e. register the on change function and call `this.onChanged(someValue)` to let the parent know. You'd need to call this in the child whenever the select changes. And use `<select-input formControlName="country"...` in parent.

Comment: where exactly to call ``this.onChanged(someValue)`` in child component ?

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5024082/4711754

Comment: Can't you just use `@Output() EventEmitter` ? Or does the `registerForm` not emit events?