# how to convert data in a string using json in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-json

I do not know exactly how I can bind my form data in JSON string. in my scenario, I use a string field in the database and have some checkbox fields that I have to save in only a single database column using JSON. for that, I created an HTML form, and I don't know how I can bind all data in a database. if someone knows then can guide me

```js
documentList: [
          {
            'IsSpecifications': false,
            'IsSpecificationscomment': ''
          },
          {
            'IsDrawSchedule': false,
            'IsDrawSchedulecomment': ''
          },
          {
            'TqRfi': false,
            'TqRficomment': ''
          },
          {
            'InsEnqReqQouInfor': false,
            'InsEnqReqQouInforcomment': ''
          },
          {
            'PanEnqReqQouInfor': false,
            'PanEnqReqQouInforcomment': ''
          },
          {
            'PanSubContQuot': false,
            'PanSubContQuotcomment': ''
          },
          {
            'MccSchedule': false,
            'MccScheduleComment': ''
          },
          {
            'ScPackQuot': false,
            'ScPackQuotComment': ''
          },
          {
            'O3rdPartyQuot': false,
            'O3rdPartyQuotcomment': ''
          },
          {
            'EquipSchedule': false,
            'EquipScheduleComment': ''
          },
          {
            'PointSchedul': false,
            'PointSchedulComment': ''
          },
          {
            'ValveSchedul': false,
            'ValveSchedulComment': ''
          },
          {
            'IdentRiskOpport': false,
            'IdentRiskOpportComment': ''
          },
          {
            'InstSubContQuot': false,
            'InstSubContQuotComment': ''
          }
        ];
```

```html
<div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="isSpecifications()" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="Drawings/Schedules" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="TQ’s / RFI’s" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox
                            label="Install Enquiry / request to quote information"
                            labelPosition="Before"
                        ></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox
                            label="Panel Enquiry / request to quote information"
                            labelPosition="Before"
                        ></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="Panel Sub Contractor Quotation" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="MCC Schedules" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="Other S/C Package Quotations" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="Other 3rd Party Quotations" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="Equipment Schedules" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="Points Schedules" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="Valve Schedules" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox
                            label="Identifed Risks and Opportunities (INCL. VALUE ENGINEERING)"
                            labelPosition="Before"
                        ></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <ejs-checkbox label="Install Sub Contractor Quotation" labelPosition="Before"></ejs-checkbox>
                    </div>
```

in the database, I use **documentlist** field in that all my checkbox values save in JSON string.

Comment: JSON.parse string when data comes into the app from server, bind object to form and JSON.stringify the form on the way out to the server.

Comment: can you explain to me how can I bind the data from the form

Comment: yes, but it'll likely be tomorrow, Suggest reading up on forms in the meantime https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview My answer will be form array + implementing control value accessor on resuseable `ejs-checkbox` component

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you searching for is JSON.parse()

See documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse?retiredLocale=it

Answer (score 0):

##### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-and-custom-checkbox-component-cva?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Main purpose of this answer is to provide  the stackblitz. This is not a tutorial.

To fully understand the code requires learning:

- Angular Reactive Forms (form group, form array etc.) - see https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
- Some RxJS (delay, takeUntil(this.destroyed$) etc.) - see https://angular.io/guide/rx-library
- Control Value Accessor (writeValue etc.) - [a previous SO answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57280011/4711754) or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVbLSN0AW-Y

Note instead of Control Value Accessor you could pass in a form group as an input. This is partly a matter of preference.

### Overview

Implementing the control value accessor on custom component `ejs-checkbox` means we can bind it via

```
<ejs-checkbox formControlName="{{ i }}"></ejs-checkbox>
```

and any changes will be reflected in the overall form group.

Make some changes to form and watch the valueChanges console logs to see this.

I've used a form array for the document list. This allows the size of the array to change. If this will not change you could replace with form controls.

I've provided an `exampleSave()` that converts the form group value to match your `documentList`. You could JSON.stringify this and send to server as described in your question.